# Employers statement on approval for holidays for Belgium Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas, belgium, business-travel

I have been invited for a job interview in Belgium by a Belgian company. I am from India and hold Indian passport.

1. Do I apply for a business visa or tourist?
2. If I apply for business visa then I need an invitation from the inviting company or organisation (which I will get) and cover letter from the applicant's current employer (clearly I can not get this as I am not going for my current employer). What should I do?
3. In the required documents sections it says that I need to provide a letter from my current employer approving my absence. How can I tell my employer that I am going to Belgium for a job interview? Is this letter a must?

Comment: You don't need to tell your employer that it's a job interview, kraft say it's a vacation, but you need a letter approving the leave.

Comment: Very normal. That document is not 'a must' in your case. You make a one sentence attestation that providing that single piece of evidence might jeopardise your employment situation.  They are not idiots and they have deep experience in handling applications from people wanting to attend a job interview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Business or tourism are not clearly defined categories with a separate list of formal requirements. The key requirement behind all this is having a legitimate and plausible purpose for the trip. So you simply need to provide documentation that makes sense and supports your plans.

Clearly, you are not going there for tourism so “business” makes more sense. The reason why they ask a letter from your current employer is that they assume that most business trips will be on behalf of that employer (think visiting clients, attending a training paid by the employer, etc.) But applying without it should be fine in this case. If you are still uneasy about “business”, you could also check “other” and write “job interview”.

Regarding your leave, I am not 100% sure of the way this works in India. Any sort of proof that your employer approves your absence would clearly be useful but do you need to be completely upfront with them about the purpose of the trip?

Comment: Thanks @Relaxed. Will be applying in other category and mentioning job interview as the purpose. Also, I will try to get a letter which does not mention the purpose of my leave and will explain at the visa interview.

Comment: Update: I applied without employers' leave approval statement. My visa application was put on hold and I was requested to provide leave approval statement. I later on provided it and got my visa approved in 2 days time.

Comment: @nambaliya Great, glad that it worked out and thanks for letting us now!